# Simular comportamiento de Ctrl + clic en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Existe alguna manera de **abrir una nueva pestaña** qué se abra aparte y que **yo permanezca en la que me encuentro** desde Javascript? Por ejemplo, cuando tu le das click a un link con la tecla 'control' oprimida, este link se abre en una nueva pestaña sin pasarte a esa nueva pestaña, es decir, **la nueva pestaña se abre pero yo permanezco en mi pestaña actual**. Quisiera simular esta funcionalidad en **Javascript**, existe alguna manera?

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiar el título por algo similar a "Simular comportamiento de Ctrl + clic en JS", ya que es un poco más descriptivo. Por cierto, si ya habías intentado hacer algo, no olvides mostrar un [repro].

Comment: Sí, es posible hacerlo, ¿Haz intentado hacer algo?...

Comment: Puede usar `window.open(url, '_blank');` para abrir una nueva pestaña, y lo puede agregar a un evento especifico

Comment: es posible abrir pestañas por código, abrirlas sin que tengan focus es otro tema, dependiendo del navegador y sus configuraciones pueden y van a ser consideradas acciones potencialmente no deseadas del tipo "popunder" y por lo tanto bloqueadas.  la mas simple es con [`window.focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus) otras técnicas ( crear elemento y enviar evento ) han sido removidas o no son soportadas por navegadores mas actuales

Comment: Considero el comentario de @aloMalbarez como la respuesta de esta pregunta, así mismo como su apunte de que los navegadores tomarán esta acción como potencialmente no deseada.